# QGIS working with Qchainage using degrees instead of meters

Tags: qgis

i'm using Qchainage on a Polygon to Line layer, and in the input dialogue there's degrees instead of meters .. and i've used trial and error to find a suitable distance ... but the issue is that not all the created points are at the same distance from each other

my process goes as follows Creating a buffer >> polygon to line >> QChainage

is there a way to input meters ?

Comment: did you check if you coodinate system is in meters?

Comment: and how to change the coordinates system for a layer?

Answer (score 1):

Save your data in a CRS that has meters as its unit of distance.  When you do, QChainage will also work in meters (it works in the units of the layer)

Comment: i cant add or import new data since i work on a server

Comment: Please be more specific on your limitations, because if you can create a QChainage layer, you surely also can create a layer where your data is saved in appropriate CRS.

Comment: so just to be clear .. i should save the layer im working on as CRS >> create the buffer >> create the polygon to line layer>> create the  Qchainage should be in meters?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  It is all down to the choice of CRS.